# Is this possible <img src="" src2="" src3=""/>?

Tags: html

I'm very new to html, css, java, code in general, and I was trying to figure out how to add more than one image within one single line of code.

I'm trying to create a really simple click-through image gallery with no flare or crazy tricks?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: So what should the image be if it sourced from 3 different places ?

Comment: it would be very simple however to write a teeny bit of js/jquery that would swap out the `src` when you click the image or similar

Comment: thank you all for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you wonder about any HTML tag look it up at W3C (They are the authority when it comes to web standards) The imagetag is found here:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html#img.attrs.src

What would would probably want is to change the image `src` attribute using javascript, or some library like jQuery. This will also let you do more advanced scripting later on.

It could look like this in pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById("img").src = "foobar.jpg";
```

Comment: how would this java look for multiple images?

Comment: Well, this is not java... Java is to javascript as a car is to carbide. they are completely unrelated, it's just that the names are similar. This javascript will just set the source, you would be a lot better off using jQuery. Have a look at the jQuery homepage and documentation.

Answer (score 6):

No. Image tags can have only ONE `src`. If you want multiple images, either use multiple image tags, or use some javascript to change the `src` of the one image.

Comment: of course its possible and will render.  its just not valid and doesn't accomplish his/her goal

Comment: possible, yes. render, maybe. valid, definitely not.

Answer (score 0):

As @Luiggi says:  no.  You can't do that in HTML. The img tag is for a single image.

If you want to click through things, then you need to have the appropriate user-interaction event handlers, and a bunch of separate objects to switch through.  Doing this is not hard, for example, you could load all the images in separate img tags, and set all but one of their display attributes to 'none'.

Then when somebody clicks, you can hide the visible one and show the next one.

Or you can go a little bit deeper and look at the many many different options for image galleries with a google search.  Most of them will require some underlying framework be loaded, such at jQuery, but once you get past that hurdle the slide show stuff is usually pretty easy.